# Can my javascript memoization be more terse?

Tags: javascript, memoization, idioms

I'm trying to store a reference in my javascript to a page element that will be interacted with frequently and using this code:

```
var breadcrumbBar = null;
function getBreadcrumbBarElement() {
    if (breadcrumbBar === null) {
        breadcrumbBar = document.getElementById(breadcrumbBarElementId);
    }
    return breadcrumbBar;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if I can be more terse or idiomatic than this (and as a result improve my javascript more generally...)?

Comment: Considering that `document.getElementById` could return `null`, wouldn't it be better to use `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use the logical `or` operator:

```
var breadcrumbBar = null;
function getBreadcrumbBarElement() {
    return breadcrumbBar || (breadcrumbBar = document.getElementById(breadcrumbBarElementId));
}
```

or, to make this a bit more generic:

```
var elementCache = {}

function getCached(id) {
    return elementCache[id] || (elementCache[id] = document.getElementById(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in order to encapsulate the cache into function:

```
function getCached(id) {
  if (!getCached.elementCache) getCached.elementCache = {}; 
  return getCached.elementCache[id] || (getCached.elementCache[id] = document.getElementById(id));
}
```